# eTA Transit -layover in Canada

Tags: canada, layovers, filipino-citizens, eta, dominican-republic

Hi I am a filipina who will go to Dominic Country without visa. My flight will layover in Canada Airport for 19hrs. Is it okay if I get eTA transit, instead of transit visa?

Comment: Can you calrify whether you hold any other visa?

Comment: Nope. I don't have visa. I am not going to get a visa because I will stay in Dominica Country for 21 days only.

Comment: Updated the answer. TL;DR - You need a transit visa.

Answer (score 2):

You need a transit visa in canada. eTA doesn't apply for Philippines.

See: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/entry-requirements-country.html#visarequired

Comment: She could be traveling to Dominica.

Comment: @phoog Sorry. Corrected the answer.

Comment: It's rather more concise now, but I can't upvote it because I already did.